# select from database

Tags: sql

For a University course I've been given the following task

Suppose that we have an employee table like (first_name, last_name, salary, hire_date, ...). There is regulation which states that every employee each year after he/she is hired, must renew his contract with company. Show how many months remain before the next renewal for each employee.

This is my attempt:

```
select (abs(months_between(sysdate,hire_date)/12 - 
         round((months_between(sysdate,e.hire_date))/12)))
from employees e
```

is it correct?or what will be correct implementation

Comment: You could already create some test data, and test your own code - in fact, provide your test case data and test results with your assignment when you submit it, unit tests are a part of development life.

Answer (score 0):

You are part of the way there, but this isn't it - what you have so far will show the modulus of months since hire date divided by 12, as a fraction.

What you need is to subtract the the modulus of months since hire date divided by 12, as a whole number, from 12.

So to take an example, an employee who was hired 13 months ago will return 0.0833333 in your supplied query - you want to see a result of (12 - (the remainder of 13/12 as a whole number - ie. 1)) = 11 months to go.

Most flavours of SQL have a modulus function, although the name and syntax may vary between SQLs.

Also, I would amend your query to include `e.*` as well as your calculation in your select statement.

Comment: modulus it is  absolute value or?

Comment: Modulus = remainder. Absolute value is irrelevant in your answer, since all it does is remove a minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with a table like this:

```
create table my_table (
  first_name varchar(15), 
  last_name varchar(15), 
  salary integer, 
  hire_date date
);

insert into my_table values ('A', 'Beemer', 30000, '2011-01-15');
insert into my_table values ('B', 'Catalog', 31000, '2011-01-27');
insert into my_table values ('C', 'Doir', 45000, '2011-03-11');
```

you can use a SELECT statement to return a result like this one.

```
first_name  last_name  salary  hire_date    renewal_date  days_to_renewal
--
A           Beemer     30000   2011-01-15   2012-01-15     57
B           Catalog    31000   2011-01-27   2012-01-27     69
C           Doir       45000   2011-03-11   2012-03-11    113
```

You should keep in mind that "month" is a fuzzy word that most database people hate with a white-hot, burning passion. It can mean 28, 29, 30, or 31 days on a real calendar.  And *you* will always get blamed when expectations don't match common sense.

Running your query against my data returns these values. Clearly wrong.

```
LAST_NAME   MONTHS_TO_RENEWAL
Beemer      .154442577658303464755077658303464755078
Catalog     .186700642174432497013142174432497013143
Doir        .310356556152927120669056152927120669056
```

[Oracle has a months_between() function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/olap.102/b14346/dml_x_monitor004.htm) that's documented to return "the number of months between two dates". You need to know exactly what "number of months" means to this function. (Again, given that a calendar month might have 28, 29, 30 or 31 days in it.) I'd be really surprised if you're expected to do the arithmetic any other way.

I'd suggest you start with this, and fill in the three missing pieces.

```
select first_name, last_name, salary, hire_date, 
       ('date arithmetic to calculate the renewal date') renewal_date, 
       months_between('one date', 'another date') months_to_renewal
from my_table;
```

Comment: sorry i was  out,i did not understand one thing  thanks for creating table code,i know it,just  if for example  person is hired at data   5 march of 2007  ,it means that left   about  3-4 month  to renew his contract,month between calculates how many months are gone after hire,so  what should add else?

Comment: so it means that this code should i use?select floor(12-mod(months_between(sysdate,hire_date), 12))
from employees

Comment: @dato: We don't have any way to know what code you should use on your homework. We can tell you whether you get the right answer or not, but you can tell that yourself, right?

Comment: it is not any problem even with code,i am interested very much and please  tell me is  my code right?